# Why my function creates a new object every time it is called?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

I have a class "Room" which has a variable of type class "Hero". The problem I face is that whenever I call a method of type: RoomObject.GetHeroObject().MethodOfHero(), a new Hero object is created. What is even stranger is that RoomObject.GetHeroObject() alway returns the same object of type "Hero", however, MethodOfHero() somehow refers to a different object every time.

```
class Hero;                     //Forward declaration

class Room {
protected:
 
    Hero *hero;
    ...
}
```

```
Hero Room::getHero(){return *hero;};
```

```
void Hero::move(char c) {
    if(c==KEY_UP){
        cout<<"up";
        moveUp();
    }
    else if(c==KEY_DOWN){
        moveDown();
        cout<<"down";
    }
    else if(c==KEY_LEFT){
        moveLeft();
        cout<<"left";
    }
    else if(c==KEY_RIGHT){
        moveRight();
        cout<<"right";
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Incorrect input";
        return;
    }

    }
```

```
int main() {
    Room unfurnished1= Room(5, 15);
    unfurnished1.getHero().move('w');
```

Comment: `Hero Room::getHero(){return *hero;};` Creates a copy of a `Hero` instance. Did you mean to return a reference? If so, the return type should be `Hero&`.

Comment: If you did `int Room::getHero() { return 3; }` would you expect `a.getHero()++;` to somehow cause the next call to `getHero()` to return 4?

Comment: I would indeed like to return a reference and not create a copy of a Hero instance. Can you elaborate a bit more on how I can achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Room::getHero()` returns a `Hero`, not a reference or a pointer to an existing `Hero`. This makes it so that a new copy of the `Hero` pointed to by `Room::hero` is made every time the function is called.

A solution for this would be to make `getHero` return either a pointer or a reference to `Room::hero`. Here is an example using a pointer:

```
Hero* Room::getHero(){ return hero; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed solved my issue! I'm rather new to C++

Comment: The answer could be improved by adding `Hero& Room::getHero() const noexcept { return *hero; }` as a second alternative.